# Iterate dictionary parallelly to reduce processing time and improve performance

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am having a dictionary like this:

```
{
  "ABC": {
    "Name": "ABC",
    "dates": {
      "2019-12-13": [
        {
          "Status": "P"
        },
        {
          "Status": "A"
        }
      ],
      "2019-12-14": [
        {
          "Status": "P"
        },
        {
          "Status": "A"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am iterating like this:

```
for key, value in result.items()
   for dkey, dvalue in value['dates'].items()
       process(key,value,dkey,dvalue)

def process(key, value, dkey, dvalue):
     ##Processing
     ##Insert into db process data
```

Can we iterate the dict. parallel to get better performance?

Comment: Have you done any benchmarking/profiling?

Comment: Almost certainly, your bottlenecks are in `def process`. The actual iteration time is negligible. Before you even begin to parallelize something, you should make sure you aren't doing anything inefficiently in `def process`, because parallelization isn't magic that you sprinkle into your code to improve performance. You can just as likely make your performance *worse8.

Comment: "Profile before optimizing" - a cite from a known good book ... It's worth to follow it

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest What book do you mean?

Comment: @StefanPochmann, "*Effective Python*"

Comment: I think @juanpa.arrivillaga makes a good point, as always. In general, multiprocessing/parallelism/those things make a program slower, not faster. Before any of that, we need to ask if performance is actually a problem, which parts of the program are responsible, work on finding possible improvements to the design and algorithms,......

Comment: Would you mind now accepting an answer or comment it to get further details ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` so run the method in parallel over values, you may use 1 argument (it's easier) so just `tuple` the values

```
def process(values):
    key, value, dkey, dvalue = values
    # do your stuff


if __name__ == '__main__':
    todos = [(key, value, dkey, dvalue)
             for key, value in result.items()
             for dkey, dvalue in value['dates'].items()] # all the tuples

    cpu_percent = 0.5 # the number of processors to use = the number of thread
    with mp.Pool(int(mp.cpu_count() * cpu_percent)) as q:
        q.map(process, todos)
```

But as you mean *insert into DB* I'd suggest to run a few query but with multiple tuples to insert, 10 insertion queries of 100 values would be better than 1000 insertion queries ;)

Comment: It’s a relatively small thing, but you can just do `mp.cpu_count() // 2`.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile it allows to do 0.25, 0.5, 0,75,... ;)

Comment: Yeah, I guess that’s true. Do you encounter many situations where you use those different ratios? I would have thought that people really only use `mp.cpu_count()`, or `mp.cpu_count() - 1`.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I do, and the OP is free to use part of or all the solution like everybody else ;)